# How to pass parameters in subquery mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

So, I have a mysql table with user id(`id`) and date of transaction(`dot`) that looks like:

```
id      dot
-------------------------------
101     2015-06-12 12:18:42 UTC
102     2015-06-12 12:18:40 UTC
103     2015-06-12 12:18:42 UTC
101     2015-07-12 12:18:42 UTC
```

and so on.
(Output for this data should be:

```
Year    Month    Num of users
-----------------------------
2015    06        0
2015    07        2
```

)
It logs all the transactions that are made. For each month `m`, I want to find out the count of users by month and year who transacted in `m-1` month but not in `m` month. The results need to be grouped by year and month. Ideally, table should look like (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b80f49/1)

```
Year    Month    Num of users
-----------------------------
2015     05          0
2015     06          2
2015     07          1
2015     08          4
```

Now for a single month(E.g. 05/2015), I can hardcode:

```
SELECT "2015" AS Year,"05" AS Month, "COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table WHERE
MONTH(dot)=4 AND YEAR(dot)=2015
AND id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE MONTH(dot)=5 AND YEAR(dot)=2015)
```

To group the count of users  using `GROUP BY`, the query would look like:

```
SELECT YEAR(dot) as Year,MONTH(dot),COUNT(DISTINCT id) as Month FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(dot_parent,dot_this_table)<30 AND DATEDIFF(dot_parent,dot_this_table)>=0)
```

Here dot_parent is the `dot` of the parent query and dot_this_table is the `dot` of the subquery. Now the problem here is that I can't pass the dot_parent inside the subquery. Is there a way to do that or frame the query in another way such that its logical structure remains similar, since I would have to make similar queries for multiple date ranges.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: What when there is a month or two with no data at all? E.g. no data for 2015-07 and 2015-08. What would you show? 2015-07 with the total user count of 2015-06 probably. And 2015-08 and 2015-09 both with a count of zero? Do they both have to appear in the results? (It's always a bit difficult to show data that does *not* exist in a table :-)

Comment: There are no empty months in between in the actual table. So, no need to handle those. For first month and last month in db, it should work as expected. Even if there are empty dates in between, I don't think they would be difficult to handle as I would probably be applying COUNT(DISTINCT id) with a condition which will give 0 when there are 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must query the same table thrice: once for the months to show, once to find the users in the previous months, once for user matches in the months in question. You'd select distinct users per month, as you are not interested in whether a user had more than one transaction in a month or not.

Here is the complete query:

```
select 
  this_month.year, 
  this_month.month,
  count(prev_month_users.user) - count(this_month_users.user) as users
from 
(
  select distinct year(timing) as year, month(timing) as month
  from transactions
) this_month
left join
(
  select distinct 
    year(timing) as year, month(timing) as month, id as user,
    year(date_add(timing, interval 1 month)) as next_month_year,
    month(date_add(timing, interval 1 month)) as next_month_month
  from transactions
) prev_month_users
  on prev_month_users.next_month_year = this_month.year
  and prev_month_users.next_month_month = this_month.month
left join
(
  select distinct year(timing) as year, month(timing) as month, id as user
  from transactions
) this_month_users
  on this_month_users.user = prev_month_users.user
  and this_month_users.year = prev_month_users.next_month_year
  and this_month_users.month = prev_month_users.next_month_month
group by this_month.year, this_month.month;
```

Result:

```
year  month  users
2015  5      0 
2015  6      2 
2015  7      1 
2015  8      3
```

Note that I show three users for August (users 101, 102, 104). User 101 had two transactions in July, but it is still three users who had transactions in July but not in August.

Here is your SQL fiddle back: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b80f49/13